# How to use GPG with IOS (Create keypair, List Keys, Import public key, encrypt, decrypt)?

Tags: ios, gnupg

In the Gnupg there is gpg implementation for different platforms, even android, but not IOS.

Is there anyway I can use GPG in my IOS app?

I am looking for the very basic operations as described in this title  (Create keypair, List Keys, Import public key, encrypt, decrypt)

I found zero material out there except for apps that use gpg within (which is what I want to accomplish)

any directions are valid

lets talk, thanks

Comment: what is the reason for the close vote?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS there is [ObjectivePGP](http://objectivepgp.com) framework that covers that functionality, you may want to use it to incorporate PGP in your application.

Answer (score 1):

[PGPro](https://pgpro.app) and [Privacy](https://privacyapp.io) are both free softwares, they rely on [ObjectivePGP](http://objectivepgp.com) and they work like a charm. Maybe there are some limitations in the support of elliptic curves but RSA just works. Please ensure that you don't mistakenly export both your public key and your secret key when using [PGPro](https://pgpro.app) when you only want to share your public key with someone else who would like to send you encrypted messages.

N.B: Please note that I don't recommend you to encrypt/decrypt messages under proprietary operating systems because it requires you to blindly trust the corporation that provides the operating system as it can't be audited by an independent organization. I recommend you to install a GNU Linux free software distribution like Debian (or Postmarket OS but it's not very mature yet) on your phone instead. As it might be unclear for some people, I highly discourage the use of OS X, iOS, Microsoft Windows and even Android to encrypt/decrypt messages.

Answer (score -3):

I am currently searching for an iOS GnuPG client app as well and found this page [Uwes Blog](https://uwe-arzt.de/2014/12/30/ios-gnupg-clients/) that lists and compares four different apps (iPGMail, oPenGP, Secumail, NouveauPG).

Comment: It only lists non free softwares :( I don't use proprietary softwares, especially when it has to deal with private keys, it's very dangerous. Those are black boxes, how could we trust them if they can't be audited? ObjectivePGP was audited by the way.